# Boost won't build x64 libraries on Windows with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, boost

I've been recently trying to build boost libraries on my windows desktop and while x86 builds just fine when I try to build x64 after dustbin'ing  it happens to be x86 and trying to compile x64 code results in  compiler  saying that library machine code(x86) does not suit project machine (x64).

I use this command to build x64: 
**b2.exe -j4 toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=minimal stage --stagedir=stage/x64**

in **project-config.jam** I also use **using msvc  : 14.1 : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe";**

Comment: Are you running the command in a x64 native tools for Visual Studio 17 command prompt? There's a shortcut to it in the start menu.

Comment: wow, I'm such an idiot, I was running native tool but plain version and not x64, hope it will work now